# One Location to Modify IMPORTRANGES

Tags: google-sheets

There are multiple spreadsheets where I'm using an INDEX MATCH lookup through external ranges combined. A new spreadsheet will be added to these combined ranges pretty frequently.

Is there a way I can change these ranges in one place, and have it automatically updated in all the spreadsheets that use the same ranges so I don't have to repeat myself?

```
INDEX(
  {
    IMPORTRANGE("1PPsERebfB1v0vHoq_imKmeU-2jC-Qr_Vofr3_2s2Sw", "accs!A:A"); // <--
    IMPORTRANGE("1cH-OHaBenP-huzMOFhf3XsNFtZA5pgP8ZCXBBaWLwE", "accs!A:A")  // <--
  },
  MATCH(
    B2,
    {
      IMPORTRANGE("1PPsERebfB1v0vHoq_imKmeU-2jC-Qr_Vofr3_2s2Sw", "accs!G:G"); // <--
      IMPORTRANGE("1cH-OHaBenP-huzMOFhf3XsNFtZA5pgP8ZCXBBaWLwE", "accs!G:G")  // <--
    },
    0
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a workbook that is solely designed to house the accumulated range
2. In a given sheet, enter the array formula representing the aggregated IMPORTRANGE, e.g. `{IMPORTRANGE(...), ...}` using `;` for columnar range concatenation and `,` for row range concatenation (as you have already done, based on your example code).
3. From your analysis sheets, reference this master workbook id and the associated range, e.g. `=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("master_wb_id", "acc!A:A"), ...)`

As noted in the [function description](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340), if the desired import is ["too large"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88520/how-to-work-around-the-importrange-error-results-too-large), the import will fail. If you get to that scale, you may want to look into a more robust solution, such as a database that allows querying.